# MySQL Connection Pool in Glassfish not working

Tags: mysql, glassfish, connection-pooling, ping

I'm trying to setup a connection pool in Glassfish for a MySQL server. But when i try and PING it it fails, server gives this error stating:

```
WARNING: RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool
[myPoolName], Connection could not be allocated because: Access denied for user 
''@'localhost' {using password: YES}
```

In my connection pool properties I did specify the password, but ping is still not working.

Comment: Seems to me that the user name is missing?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, what would my username be? I didn't specify one when i created my mysql database. As far as I know I'm just 'root'?

Comment: MySQL server often has root/pass combination by default. In your connection pool you should give the username and the password. You could try to connect with a different client to test the correct credentials (e.g. your IDE or MySQL Workbench or MySQL command line ...)

Comment: unbelievable, I went and changed my username properties to 'root' and sure enough the ping worked! Thanks for the push in the right direction Matt. Also I tried connection through Workbench

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the user name is missing.

MySQL server often has root/pass combination by default. In your connection pool you should give the username *and* the password. You could try to connect with a different client to test the correct credentials (e.g. your IDE or MySQL Workbench or MySQL command line ...)